# Ошибка при парсинге 503

Tags: python, requests, cookie, get

Я уже не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что при поптыке парсинга сайта при помощи requests.get, сервер возвращает мне код 503

```
import requeests

headers = {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36"
    }

url = 'https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/instrument/i-oborudovanie-po-vidam-rabot/dlya-rabot-s-kartonom-i-bumagoj/page2/#goods'

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(req.status_code)
```

Хотелось бы понять, что мне надо передать еще, чтобы меня 'пустили' и почему я должен это добавить?

Comment: "Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded. This response should be used for temporary conditions and the Retry-After HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service." А в тексте страницы что написано? Может реально сайт упал или закрыт на обслуживание.

Comment: Тут виноват (изменил ссылку на страницу 2), но суть вопроса та же

Comment: Там какая-то защита от роботов похоже, но что она хочет - я пока не понял.

Comment: Сайт на cloudflare. В принципе тут есть ответ (https://community.cloudflare.com/t/503-http-response/31619). Но в любом случае это надо cloudflare уточнять как можно обойти без coockie и js. Вроде пишут нужен какой-то connection header

Answer (score 1):

Мне в данном случае помогла библиотека cloudscraper для обхода бликоровок cloudflare

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

req = scraper.get("https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/instrument/i-oborudovanie-po-vidam-rabot/dlya-rabot-s-kartonom-i-bumagoj/page2/#goods")
print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: Да, в `Google Colab` тоже работает, полезное